# Shortcut command creation for scp linux command

Tags: linux, bash, scp

Hi i want to run a linux command that automates a scp with the location of origin that varies and the destination location that remains contant.
For example -

```
scp 123.txt abc@example.com:~/
```

the destination (abc@example.com) will always be the same, however the file name (123.txt) will always be different.

I would like to run this entire scp command (scp 123.txt abc@example.com:~/) without typing the destination location

note: (abc@example.com in this case might seem short however i have a much more complex destination that is cumbersome to type out every single time)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using a function instead of an alias.  Put the following function in your .bashrc file.

```
function do-scp() {
    scp "$1" abc@example.com:~/
}
```

And thus you invoke it as follows:

```
do-scp 123.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in bash, for example:

```
my_scp()
{
  scp $1 abc@example.com:~/
}
```

and use

```
$my_scp 123.txt
```

You can put them in ~/.bash_profile so that they are always available